# How can I display html code on vue template from html file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filereader

I'd like to display html code of external html file on vue component template.

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <pre>
            <code>
                {{readFile('./code/code.html')}}
            </code>
        </pre>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        readFile: function(url) {
            return 'html code of html file.'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: in read file you should do an xhr (ajax, fetchAPI, axios) call to your html page and just use the response...

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div v-html="compiledHtml"></div>

data: function() {
    return {
      fileName: "terms.html",
      input: ""

    };
  },
     created() {
        this.fileName = this.$route.params.fileName;
        this.loadFile()
    }
    computed: {
        compiledHtml: function() {
          return this.input;
        }
      },
    methods: {

        loadFile() {
          axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "../../static/" + this.fileName
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.input = result.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.error("error getting file");
            });
        }
      },
```

the trick is the computed property